# SQLite: Extract data from the `-wal` file

Tags: sqlite, recovery, write-ahead-logging

Yesterday I accidentally deleted an SMS banking notification thread on my Android device.

A classic case: I didn't backup the messages for very long time.

After flashing the recovery and rooting the device I pulled the `mmssms.db` SQLite3 database along with its `-shm` and `-wal` files. Inspecting the contents of the database didn't give a chance to recover the messages: neither the `threads` nor the `sms` tables provide a "soft deletion" column, so the messages are deleted from the database physically.

However, grepping for the banking notification text in the `-wal` file resulted in very many occurrences of the notification plain text so I'm sure: the data is locked there somehow. Opening the database using `sqlite3` merely deletes the `-wal` file.

I'm wondering: is it possible to extract the data out of the `-wal` file or rollback the deletion (at least for both `threads` and `sms` tables) merging the deleted contents back to the `mmssms.db` database?

Comment: Check the [WAL contents](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_write_ahead_log): does it contain valid frames?

Comment: @CL. I believe so. There was no crash at the time of the accident, so I believe both the database its WAL/SHM are not corrupted. Is there probably a tool to inspect the WAL contents?

Comment: No. You have to go at it with a hex editor, or pay somebody else.

Comment: @CL. Ok, let's suppose I implement the tool to verify the WAL contents integrity myself. What then?

Comment: The WAL file contains the changed pages of all transactions since the last checkpoint. Removing some frames essentially reverts those transactions.

Comment: @CL. Okay, having some C background from the past I've implemented a tool that verifies (no checksums for frames though) and dumps valid-looking frames into separate files: it scans entire WAL file and dumps pages only if salt matches the file header salt. There are 265 dump files in total. grepping the dump files for the bank messages resulted 43 files only. A quick look at the grep result makes me think that disassembling the WAL file won't help: dumped pages 4K each lack the text the thread collected for years. I want to believe that I'm wrong at understanding it though.

Comment: @CL. Also, to my understanding, if the wanted data is removed data is deleted from the database physically, removing such frames would merely make the data completely gone.

Comment: The WAL file contains the *new* data, i.e., some metadata that says "there is no row here". (If you simply remove the WAL file, you get the state after the last checkpoint. This might be too early.)

Comment: @CL. Oh, I see now, yeah, that makes perfect sense to me and truly smart. Sorry for not seeing such a simple thing. So, I believe, the data is lost now as I don't believe the database and its WAL file are in the state I can recover from (I just can't tell how much data might change so did the `mmssms*` files since then). But it was really interesting, so thank you for your comments!